# Is it possible connect to google talk xmpp server using BOSH?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I'm using SMACK library (JAVA) to handle XMPP connection on an android platform and i would like to know if google support BOSH.

Recently my mobile operator locked some ports and now i'm limited to 80 and 8080 ports so BOSH would be a great solution.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after some research and tests i conclude that is possible to connect using port 80 instead 5222 recommended by google. Connecting via port 80 doesn't use BOSH so you can use any XMPP client library to connect over.

Comment: However, you won't be able to use port 80 if your ISP (or mobile operator) is using an http[s] proxy to serve your requests. You would have to switch to BOSH in that case.

Comment: Yes, you can log in to your XMPP account via the bosh endpoint at https://www.jappix.com/bind